# pod WEPopover popover menu is not appearing as currentTopViewcontroller. Instead it is going to the back of currentTopviewController view hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13

In iOS 13 Popover view menu is not being displayed on the on visible UIWindow although it is present in the view hierarchy of the keyWindow as can be seen here

[image]

This is the way i am presenting the popover menu:

```
WEPopoverController *popover = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:menuVc];
    self.popoverController = popover;
    if ([popover respondsToSelector:@selector(setContainerViewProperties:)]) {
        [popover setContainerViewProperties:[CPGlobals popoverStyling]];
    }
    popover.delegate = self;
    //self.popoverController.passthroughViews =
    //[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.navigationController.navigationBar];

    menuVc.containerPopover = popover;

    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems[0]
                                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Expected:

[image]

Actual:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In WEPopoverController.m, change method keyView() from:

```
if (w.subviews.count > 0) {
    return [w.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
} else {
    return w;
}
```

to:

```
if (w.subviews.count > 0) {
    return [w.subviews objectAtIndex:[w.subviews count]-1];
} else {
    return w;
}
```